# My Iphone wont mount to ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, iphone

It wont mount when I do lsusb it shows apple iphone 4s but I cant find it in my devices or filemanager or even music players so im trying to get it in virtualbox so I can jailbreak it but virtualbox is showing other usbs but not my Iphone